# Download Content Dynamically to App through In-App

Tags: iphone, download, in-app-purchase

I am trying to download content dynamically to my App after an In-App purchase.  This content needs to be decompressed.  What is the best way to do this and to uncompress and access the data?

I always want to give the user the ability to pause the download.  How do you do that programmatically - the pause and resume?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/

You could try to do the uncompress in a separate thread; the download should be run asynchronously, of course.